# last modified rows timestamp for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

Is there a feature/script to check when was the last time a row has been modified/changed in SQL 2016+ tables?Does SQL track this automatically or do we have a feature which gives this info? Please let me know your thoughts/

Answer (score 1):

Noting done by default. You can turn on stuff like temporal (probably overkill) or create a trigger to update the table.

SQL Server keeps track of all modification internally, in the transaction log, for its own purposes (like rollback and crash recovery). But the log is volatile and even if you get there before the info is gone, you'd have to decode the info yourself using unsupported means (like fn_dblog).

[Edit] Adding in the options *Change Tracking* (lower overhead) and *Change Data Capture* (higher overhead and uses an Agent job but gives more info than CT), as suggested in the comments below by Dominique.

Comment: Be careful in both cases if you need to detect actual changes and ignore effective "no operation" updates. If you run `UPDATE MyTable SET AColumn = 'value' WHERE AColumn = 'value'` it will not change any data but will generate new entries in your history if using temporal tables for the rows that already have `AColumn=='value1'`. Of course you can filter these out in queries if needed and you know they may be there. The same goes for simple trigger implementations (though you can add logic here to alter that behaviour if the potential performance drop is worth it).

Comment: You could also look at Change Tracking or Change Data Capture (CDC). I guess both option could give you information about the last modification (per table). It also may be lighter then temporal tables.

Comment: I was looking at temporal tables and i dont want to maintain a history of the record. All i want is when was the last time the row has been changed. Hence if i create a temporal table like this without the clause SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.xyz)) in create table syntax. then im able to get the last row modification timestamp. Do you see any issues with this approach??

Comment: Yes, you are probably using a sledgehammer when a tiny screwdriver would be enough. :-) One thing to consider is how to handle the history. I.e., purging of old history rows. Also, will you have some batch reading off of the history table and storing what you need somewhere else? Etc. I.e., design aspect. But I suggest you look into other options first. In order with lowest overhead first, I think: CT, triggers, CDC.

Answer (score -3):

You can retrieved everything by fn_dblog as SQL server tracks all the changes in transaction log. But, CDC feature is the best for your case.

Comment: Can you really? What if the database is in simple recovery? Why is CDC the best option? I think this answer is too simple